# Mongodb Geospatial index does not support $box?

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a 2dsphere index and trying to utilize it for my geospatial queries. However, I find when I use $geoWithin.$box, it does not use the index, hence, very slow. If I use $geoWithin.$geometry, then the index will be used. The [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#behavior) says $box supports index, so I must be miss something. Any idea?

### Geospatial Index

```
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "details.lonlat" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "name" : "longlat",
            "ns" : "realestate.property",
            "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    }
```

### Query with GeoJSON polygon uses the index

```
> db.property.find({'details.lonlat': {'$geoWithin': {$geometry: {type:'Polygon', coordinates: [[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3], [1,1]]]}}}}).explain()

"inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "details.lonlat" : "2dsphere"
                                        },
...
```

### Using $box does not use index, but collection scan (why?)

```
> db.property.find({'details.lonlat': {'$geoWithin': {'$box': [[ 0, 0 ], [ 100, 100 ] ]}}}).explain()
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                    "filter" : {
                            "details.lonlat" : {
                                    "$geoWithin" : {
                                            "$box" : [
                                                    [
                                                            0,
                                                            0
                                                    ],
                                                    [
                                                            100,
                                                            100
                                                    ]
                                            ]
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                    "direction" : "forward"
```

### Mongodb Info

```
            "version" : "3.0.4",
            "gitVersion" : "0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2dsphere does not support $box query. That's why your query falls to a full collection scan.

The box [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#behavior) states the following:

```
Only the 2d geospatial index supports $box
```

Adding a 2d index should do the trick, something like:

```
db.property.ensureIndex({"details.lonlat": "2d"});
```